# Can Liquid screen protector be applied to the back of a phone

Tags: charging, hardware, lg, nfc

This is more of a hardware question...
I got my LG V30 recently, and after a few days of usage without a case, I noticed I got a feel minor scratches, and one bigger one.

My question is this? Can I apply a liquid glass screen protector to the back of my phone too, to add some protection, qnd cover up the scratches I made.. Would that interfere with things like wireless charging or NFC?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A screen protector, except a minority of extreme ones, don't interfere with any electric parts of your phone. It doesn't even contain any metal, usually. So there's no way that it can affect your mobile signal, NFC and blah blah blah. Its only use is to protect surfaces from scratches.

Comment: So its completely fine to put one on the back?.

Comment: @Eddie Yes. (Sí.)

Comment: @Eddie I have a protector on every phone I own, but personally I prefer a case rather than a piece of film or glass protector, as the latter won't protect the edges, especially corners, from collision (when my phone falls down).

Comment: I do have a case, but I would also like to apply a liquid screen protector to the back and the front. Since I have a few minor scratches on the back, and the liquid screen protector would fill those in